# UVs Blender - how can i: auto seam hard 90° edges, unfold uv, orient uv, straighten uv

Tags: uv

i´m coming from maya and want to make the swtich to blender. i need some help with uv.

my video explains in detail what i want to do in blender:

https://youtu.be/SKh-La_fW1o

edit: as you wish all with pictures. but watch the video if something is still unclear its only 1 minute. thank you

1) auto seam, adds seems on all hard 90° angle edges
[image: auto seam]

2) unfold unfold function like in maya

[image: before unfold]
[image: after unfold]

3) orient shell
[image: before orient]
[image: after orient]

Still no help, let’s me think Blender can’t do it? Thats sad I wish I can replace maya with Blender I just need to develope my workflow

Comment: Include screenshots please of what you want to do and text description in the question body

Comment: it does not allow me to add more than 8 pictures in one link. i still need more. please just watch the video. its only around 1 minute and super much on spot.

Comment: On a happy note, IMHO could be done via scripting.

Comment: Please, try to stick with one question per post, as this site requires. The aim is to host very specific questions that get very specific answers. It also helps to get much better answers, usually.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with hardops addon.

Comment: Hi, maybe this is a bit too short to be a useful answer.. try to add more info about the addon, and possibly some useful steps to follow with it, to perform at least one of the required steps...